# getting aggregates of aggregates in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In pandas, if I do this:

```
meanData = df.groupby('somecol')[fieldList].agg(np.mean)
```

And then I want to get aggregates on that (e.g. std and 25% quantile) I know I can do this:

```
meanData.std()
meanData.quantile(.25)
```

But is there a way to do it in one statement and get all the data in a single series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [DataFrame.describe()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html).

From your example:

```
df.groupby('somecol')[fieldList].agg(np.mean).describe()
```